# Url for Force Download PDF on Webview

Tags: javascript, php, android

How to make URL/link for force download pdf on webview

example url/link like this :

```
mytableview.php?export=pdf&amp;id=4&amp;custom=1&=?download
```

I try to add `=?download`

This can't force download (I mean can not auto-save)

Thanks

Comment: Need more context and some code that will translate HTML into PDF.

Comment: hi sir thanks for reply, i'm using jquery.fileDownload.min.js for javascript but can not auto/force download

Answer (score 0):

You can not just get PDF out of HTML. There should be some code on a backend which will translate the HTML content into PDF page.

https://pdfcrowd.com/blog/convert-html-to-pdf-in-php/

here is an example how other developer have achieve it. There also should be also ready php lib that you can use.

Once PDF is generated then you can attempt to dowload it using a download lib.

Comment: hi sir thanks for reply, i'm using phpmaker and for pdf phpmaker using dompdf, and for get pdf file phpmaker using jquery.fileDownload.min.js for download, but can't auto save sir

Comment: @creat15 can you provide an code that is in `mytableview.php` for more context ?
And possibly the `.js` code that triggers the `fileDownload` action